# Inactive session in Oracle by JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc

We have a web service written in Java and is connecting to Oracle database for data extraction. Recently, we encountered too many inactive session in Oracle database from JDBC which is our web service.

We are very sure that all the connection is being closed and set to null after every process.

Can anyone help us in this? Why is it causing inactive session in the database and what can be the solution to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What, exactly, is the problem?

Normally, the middle tier application server creates a connection pool.  When your code requests a connection, it gets an already open connection from the pool rather than going through the overhead of spawning a new connection to the database.  When your code closes a connection, the connection is returned to the pool rather than going through the overhead of physically closing the connection.  That means that there will be a reasonable number of connections to the database where the `STATUS` in `V$SESSION` is "INACTIVE" at any given point in time.  That's perfectly normal.

Even under load, most database connections from a middle tier are "INACTIVE" most of the time.  A status of "INACTIVE" merely means that at the instant you ran the query, the session was not executing a SQL statement.  Most connections will spend most of their time either sitting in the connection pool waiting for a Java session to open them or waiting on the Java session to do something with the data or waiting on the network to transfer data between the machines.

Are you actually getting an error (i.e. ORA-00020: maximum number of processes exceeded)?  Or are you just confused by the number of entries in `V$SESSION`?

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for the reply. The problem is that there are too many INACTIVE entries in the database and is reaching the threshold. Is there a way to get rid of those INACTIVE entries?

Comment: @sprenna - What does "reaching the threshold" mean?  Are you getting an error (i.e. ORA-00020)?  Are you using connection pools in your middle tier?  Are you certain that the INACTIVE sessions in the database aren't simply the connections that are in your connection pool(s)?

Comment: Justin, reaching threshold means exceeding the maximum number of session allowed. I modified my database connection codes in Java and the issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @lanthe We also have the same problem with boneCP connection pool. Could you please explain what modification you have done in your Java code in order to avoid the issue?

Comment: Hi Justin, Is there a way to find out from DB point of view at which point in time a particular session from the connection pool has become active and how long is that particular is been idle?