# web application creates inactive session in Oracle by jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We have a web application written in Java and is connecting to Oracle database for data extraction. Recently, we encountered too many inactive session in Oracle database from JDBC which is our web application using grails framework. Even if we click on refresh button in UI Page the INACTIVE SESSION size increasing. Which will be hanging around for long time (in days).

We are very sure that all the connection is being closed and set to null after every process.

Can anyone help us in this? Why is it causing inactive session in the database and what can be the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

> We are very sure that all the connection is being closed and set to null after every process.

If you close connections manually (which seems to be the case, if you use JDBC), why don't you use logging to analyze what's causing creating new connections?

Maybe you also use connection pool? Maybe you connect to ORACLE in a Shared mode?

There could be too many *maybes* until you provide more information.

**Update:**

In the comments, you said that you explicitly closing *connection pool*. **Why**?
It's highly recommended to use a connection pool, so your application won't spawn a new connection every time it needs to interact with database, instead using the one from pool.
So, first make sure, you actually use connection pool. Most likely you use an application server (if so, than specify which one), and I also doubt that you use plain JDBC. Most likely, it's Hibernate or any other persistence provider, right?

See also:
[Inactive session in Oracle by JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569446/inactive-session-in-oracle-by-jdbc)

Comment: yes, we are using connection pooling,(javax.sql.PooledConnection) for getting connections and our Oracle in DEDICATED MODE.

Comment: even refresh in UI page the INACTIVE SESSION size increased.

Comment: i have made the javax.sql.pooledconnection closed in finally block and assign null aswell , but still i can able to see the INACTIVE SESSIONS IN DB .code is like ...finally{_pconn.close(); 
_pconn = null;                 OBTContext.info("_pconn.close()"+_pconn);
}

Comment: No jobs running – just browsing the console ,i saw a single console incur 49 inactive sessions and 75 processes in the db and the app server memory hit 54%.  ,this is really paining.

Comment: jFrencetc:In the comments, you said that you explicitly closing connection pool. Why? Anil: i want see if any reference will left,that also close,so i closed explicitly ,for checking purpose.

Comment: i am using Jetty server and connection pool i use javax.sql api and hibernate persistence provider.thanks for quick response,Regards,

Comment: as per this reference i made explicite close,http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t142384-inactive-oracle-sessions-due-to-jsp.html