# Inactive sessions in the database

Tags: oracle, apache, tomcat, webserver

In short what we have is this - A tomcat server running, which will connect to the database after a user logs in from a page at a specific url. Once the user disconnects from the application by clicking logout, and closes the browser; the database still shows the tomcat session running when we check the sessions. The DBA has to go and kill the inactive sessions to avoid issues.

Until now it was ok, but over a period of time these 'inactive' sessions go on increasing to a limit where it requires an application server re-start to clean up the inactive sessions and to avoid HTTP 503 bad gateway error message for the users. What are we missing out here? Some parts of the application code does seem to have a problem and we are checking that, but apart from that; what else setting/changes do we need to do to avoid this issue? Is there any way to get these sessions killed automatically after the user logs out?

[image: Inactive DB sessions]

Note - I did go through this question here - [Inactive JDBC sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569446/inactive-session-in-oracle-by-jdbc) but we don't have any DB error reported. All we get is an HTTP 503 - Bad gateway error message in the browser for the users and the database slows down to a crawl.

Comment: I don't know anything about Tomcat, but my first guess would be that you search for a limit on database connections/sessions in your Java tier connection pool setup.

Comment: No idea if relevant to you, but here ( https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html ) is some info about `maxActive` and `maxIdle` properties.

Comment: Are you using any DB pool? Are you closing connections after usage in the code?

Comment: Multisync, This point I will have to confirm.

Comment: In the code we are using session.invalidate() after the user clicks on logout. DB pool - no, I don't think so. Isn't it specified in the context.xml file of tomcat? I did not see any such code in the context.xml

Comment: On the database please check `show parameter processes` and `show parameter sessions` Compare those two parameters with your maxActive and maxIdle properties.