# Large amount of Inactive sessions in Oracle by Java

Tags: java, session

I have a web application which needs to connect to the database every now and then, I am sure that I am closing every instance of new connection that I am opening. 
**The issue is** I have a lot of inactive sessions in oracle db of same user. I have tried pooling, I have tried to close all sessions but nothing seems to work fine. I have searched for possible solutions over Stack Overflow but unfortunately did not find answer to my solution. The closest I get to is [Inactive session in Oracle by JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569446/inactive-session-in-oracle-by-jdbc) where the person asking the question has itself answer the question by saying that he modified the code.

Any answer, recommendation would be appreciated

Comment: All i can say is that inactive sessions affect the performance by a very low percentage.  Have a look at this thread  for some idea, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2351843

Comment: You must be thinking about another question than the one you linked to, the one linked to has an accepted answer which says "inactive sessions are not a sign of a problem". Which is generally true unless there are many more sessions than you configure in your pool.

Answer (score 1):

*I have tried pooling...*

Without a connection pool your application has a direct controll about opening and closing the database connections. This is not the typical case as the acquiring of a physical connection is a costly operation.

A connection pool optimizes it while keeping a particular number of connection open and provides them on request to the application.

If a connection is closed by application, it is not closed in the DB, it is made available in the pool as *idle*. You can control among other parameters **how many idle connections should be kept in the pool**. E.g. for [DBCP](http://ttps://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) check the parameters *minIdle* and *maxIdle*. Except for some special cases with invalid connections, the number of idle connection (those connenction are INACTIVE) you see should be within this limit.

If you see a systematic a higher number (or even an increasing number) of INACTIVE session, the most probable explanation is that the application gets the connection from the pool and "forget" to return it - those session are INACTIVE as well.