# Time stamp of Active and Inactive session in Oracle 10g by JDBC

Tags: java, oracle

The following explains how exactly the Middle tier handles the connection pool and connections to tge DB.

[Inactive session in Oracle by JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569446/inactive-session-in-oracle-by-jdbc)

What I would like to know from DB point of view is at which point in time a particular session from the connection pool has become active and how long is that particular session or session ID is been active and idle?

The following gets me the no.of sessions made to the DB

#

(select sysdate, TRUNC(logon_time,''HH''),COUNT(*) NO_OF_SESSIONS, username from v$session where username IS NOT NULL GROUP BY TRUNC(logon_time,''HH''), USERNAME)

#

Thanks

Comment: From the DB point of view? When the pool opens the connection. The pool tracks active/inactive - the database sees a (potentially idle) user.

Comment: Yes, either from v$session or $active_session_history? Any trace of what time a session ID from the pool tried to query and how long?